# How to Stop Jquery.TinyMCE From Submitting the from when I click Save button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Whenever I click the Save button of Tinymce Editor, the form is submitting to the server. I need to stop form submission. I have searched a lot but could not find any solution. Here is my code,

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    paste_retain_style_properties : "margin, padding, width, height, font-size, font-weight, font-family, color, text-align, ul, ol, li, text-decoration, border, background, float, display",
    script_url : path_global+'/js/TinyMCE/tiny_mce.js',
    valid_children : "+body[style]",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
     setup : function(ed) {         
      ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, l) {
       });
  }
});
```

**Update:**  I have found the answer. Digging into the source I found that I can add onsubmit = "return false" on form tag  which will stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Remove the save button from the controls template. That's what it does.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, there is no way to submit the form through ajax?

Comment: That would be a different question, wouldn't it? (One I think has already been asked and answered here).

Comment: @AndrewBarber, please provide me the link (with working example if possible)? I will be very very thankful to you. Actually, see above, I am using ed.onSaveContent.add to send ajax request. Note that I am using jquery.tinymce.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, can I ask a new question for ajax?

Comment: @AndrewBarber, Digging into the source and found that I can add onsubmit="return false", which will stop the form from submitting. Thanks any way.

Comment: +1, you should post your answer as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. Digging into the source I found that I can add,

```
onsubmit = "return false"
```

on the form tag which will stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it seems obvious but I even tried capturing the form submission with jQuery and aborting it using $('#element').submit(function(){ return false; }); but wasn't working and I was going insane.